# Adding a conditional column broke the entire page

Tags: web-part, list, column

I added a conditional column to a list, it had a complicated algorithm to determine the value. I'm sure I had a syntax error in it, however now I can't even access it. When I try to view the list, I get the error...

Error 
The "ListViewWebPart" Web Part appears to be causing a problem. Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

Web Parts Maintenance Page: If you have permission, you can use this page to temporarily close Web Parts or remove personal settings. For more information, contact your site administrator.

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

### Correlation ID: 85d71f52-7f6f-42f9-901e-659b65eb1f31

I'm using SP 2010 Enterprise.

Does anyone know how I can change the contents of that conditional column and save my list???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the GUID of the list, then it should be easy.

Type - `http://servername:portnumber/_layouts/listedit.aspx?List={GUID}` in the URL and then you will be redirected to the list settings page where you will be able to modify the columns.

To find GUID of the list type this in PowerShell -

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://servername:portnumber
$list = $web.Lists["List Name"]
$list.ID
```

Comment: Thanks Deepu I'll try that and let you know if it worked for me.

Comment: Wow, that worked great. Thanks for the help! I figured out another way to delete the column, but yours is better. I'll post it below.

Answer (score 0):

Get all the columns...

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://yoursite
$list = $web.GetListFromURL("Lists/yourlist/AllItems.aspx")
foreach ($column in $list.Fields){
    $column | Select-Object -Property InternalName
}
```

then delete the column

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -identity http://yoursite
$list = $web.Lists["yourlist"]
$column = $list.Fields["yourcolumnname"]
$column.Hidden = $false
$column.ReadOnlyField = $false
$column.Update()
$list.Fields.Delete($column)
```